# Counts and percentages of several factors from data in a long format

Tags: r, dplyr, count, categorical-data

For a current project involving repeated measurements I am working with a long dataset for the firs time.

I am trying to get descriptive statistics (count, percentage) per timepoint for several categorical variables.

My data:

```
library(dplyr)

questiondata <- structure(list(id = c(2, 2, 6, 6, 9, 9, 22, 22, 23, 23, 25, 25, 
30, 30, 31, 31, 33, 33, 34, 34), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("time1", "time2"), class = "factor"), age = c(65, 
69.17, 76.75, 81.05, 58.64, 62.71, 59.37, 63.56, 58, 61.69, 55.78, 
59.95, 59.3, 63.36, 60.45, 64.39, 56.3, 60.08, 59.53, 63.84), 
    sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("men", 
    "women"), class = "factor"), hypert_drug = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Which corresponds to the following tibble:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
      id time    age sex   hypert_drug
   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct> <fct>      
 1     2 time1  65   men   no         
 2     2 time2  69.2 men   yes        
 3     6 time1  76.8 women yes        
 4     6 time2  81.0 women yes        
 5     9 time1  58.6 men   no         
 6     9 time2  62.7 men   no         
 7    22 time1  59.4 men   no         
 8    22 time2  63.6 men   no         
 9    23 time1  58   women no         
10    23 time2  61.7 women no         
11    25 time1  55.8 men   no         
12    25 time2  60.0 men   no         
13    30 time1  59.3 women no         
14    30 time2  63.4 women yes        
15    31 time1  60.4 men   yes        
16    31 time2  64.4 men   yes        
17    33 time1  56.3 men   no         
18    33 time2  60.1 men   no         
19    34 time1  59.5 women no         
20    34 time2  63.8 women no
```

To get counts of sex per time I not have:

```
long_dataset %>% 
  group_by(time, sex) %>% 
  summarize(n_sex=n())
```

Which produces the following output:

```
summarise()` has grouped output by 'time'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   time [5]
   time  sex   n_sex
   <fct> <fct> <int>
 1 time1 men     398
 2 time1 women   371
 3 time2 men     398
 4 time2 women   371
 5 time3 men     398
 6 time3 women   371
 7 time4 men     804
 8 time4 women   917
 9 time5 men    1202
10 time5 women  1288
```

What I am trying to do is also get a column for the proportion of men and women per timepoint, as well as similar columns describing the counts and percentages per timepoint for the variable 'hypert_drug'.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following your example long_dataset. Simply extend your dplyr chain.

```
library(dplyr)
long_dataset <- structure(list(id = c(2, 2, 6, 6, 9, 9, 22, 22, 23, 23, 25, 25, 
                                      30, 30, 31, 31, 33, 33, 34, 34), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                          2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                          2L), .Label = c("time1", "time2"), class = "factor"), age = c(65, 
                                                                                                                                                        69.17, 76.75, 81.05, 58.64, 62.71, 59.37, 63.56, 58, 61.69, 55.78, 
                                                                                                                                                        59.95, 59.3, 63.36, 60.45, 64.39, 56.3, 60.08, 59.53, 63.84), 
                               sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("men", 
                                                                                                     "women"), class = "factor"), hypert_drug = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

long_dataset %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(time,sex,hypert_drug) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(count = n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(count_freq = count / sum(count))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#> # Groups:   time, sex [4]
#>   time  sex   hypert_drug count count_freq
#>   <fct> <fct> <fct>       <int>      <dbl>
#> 1 time1 men   no              5      0.833
#> 2 time1 men   yes             1      0.167
#> 3 time1 women no              3      0.75 
#> 4 time1 women yes             1      0.25 
#> 5 time2 men   no              4      0.667
#> 6 time2 men   yes             2      0.333
#> 7 time2 women no              2      0.5  
#> 8 time2 women yes             2      0.5
Created on 2021-06-28 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

#### UPDATE

Not sure how to do this in a single dplyr chain. Here's a tripple dplyr chain. Maybe someone else do better. I hope, I understood you correct with the output.

```
library(dplyr)
long_dataset <- structure(list(id = c(2, 2, 6, 6, 9, 9, 22, 22, 23, 23, 25, 25, 
                                      30, 30, 31, 31, 33, 33, 34, 34), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                          2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                          2L), .Label = c("time1", "time2"), class = "factor"), age = c(65, 
                                                                                                                                                        69.17, 76.75, 81.05, 58.64, 62.71, 59.37, 63.56, 58, 61.69, 55.78, 
                                                                                                                                                        59.95, 59.3, 63.36, 60.45, 64.39, 56.3, 60.08, 59.53, 63.84), 
                               sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("men", 
                                                                                                     "women"), class = "factor"), hypert_drug = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

sex <- long_dataset %>%
  dplyr::group_by(time,sex) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n_sex = dplyr::n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(freq_sex = n_sex / sum(n_sex)) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()


drug <- long_dataset %>%
  dplyr::group_by(time,hypert_drug) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n_drug = dplyr::n()) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(freq_drug = n_drug / sum(n_drug)) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::select(-time)
  
dplyr::bind_cols(sex,drug)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>   time  sex   n_sex freq_sex hypert_drug n_drug freq_drug
#>   <fct> <fct> <int>    <dbl> <fct>        <int>     <dbl>
#> 1 time1 men       6      0.6 no               8       0.8
#> 2 time1 women     4      0.4 yes              2       0.2
#> 3 time2 men       6      0.6 no               6       0.6
#> 4 time2 women     4      0.4 yes              4       0.4
Created on 2021-06-29 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Comment: Thanks!
But this does not do exactly what I want. Now this is showing if patients use drugs also per sex, but that is not what I want. What I would like is there just to be grouped on time and then get the counts for both sex and hypert_drug.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is it that what you wanted?